# How do I reconnect this small black wire?

Tags: hard-drive, display

This small black wire became disconnected while attempting to remove the hard drive mount from an HP Slimline Desktop computer.

Now when I try and turn the computer on there is no display signal. I'm assuming it has to do with this little black wire. There are 2 of them, one is connected fine and the other is disconnected.

Here is an image of what I'm talking about. How do I reconnect this? I've tried carefully sticking it back in but it doesn't stay.

[image]

Comment: You just push in to the circle hole to the left of it. it should just snap in.

Comment: That's a wifi or other wireless antenna, not a display connector.

Comment: “Now when I try and turn the computer on there is no display signal.” The wire and socket you are showing are basically antenna wires for a wireless card—the label reads “Realtek RTL8723BE” which is a Wi-Fi card—but when you say, “There is no display signal…” that would have 100% nothing to do with a Wi-Fi antenna coming lose. Something else is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That wire is an antenna for the WiFi card, which the other is connected to.  Simply center it over the connector and press down.  It is a friction fit, meaning there will be no snap or click.

However, this has *nothing* to do with the display.  If you are having an issue with the display, that is an entirely different issue.  If you want to ask a question about the display, that should be in a different post altogether, as it is unrelated to the wire.

Comment: I managed to do it! I just had to put a bit more pressure and it clicked in place. I also got the display working by resetting the CMOS by pulling the battery. Thanks a lot for your help!